# DC.js - adding loading GIF when dc.js charts are being filtered

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to add a loading gif when a user clicks on a dc.js chart, a loading gif will appears stating that the dashboard is loading or filtering. When finish filtering, the loading gif will disappear. I have multiple charts in the dashboard. I think it would be tedious to state the .on('filtered', function(chart,filter){...}) to each chart. Is there a way or an API that will start an event whenever any charts are being filtered?

It tried using this but it doesn't support the .on(...) function

> dc.on('filtered', function(...){...});

UPDATE!
I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly. Like i saw above, I'm trying to add a feature when a user click on a row chart (dc.js), a loading gif will appear and will disappear after the charts finish redrawing or filter. I apply the code by over riding the onclick so the DIV (loading gif) will appear on the onclick then filter the charts.

```
        chart.on("renderlet", function(chart) {


        chart.selectAll('rect')
        .on('click', function(d) {
            $('#please-wait').css("display","block");
            console.log("click!", d);

            var filter = chart.keyAccessor()(d);

                dc.events.trigger(function () {
                    chart.filter(filter);
                    chart.redrawGroup();
                    $('#please-wait').css("display","none");
                });

        }); 

    });
```

Though, it sort of works. As in, if i remove the display: none line code, the please-wait will appear. If I apply the display:none line code, nothing happens because (I'm assume) the page quickly trigger the filter event before the please-wait div is actually appear in the front page. Is there a way to start the dc.events.trigger.. AFTER the please-wait Div actually appear in the front page? Am i doing this correctly or is there a better way?

Comment: I'm in exact same scenario. Any help from the community is highly appreciated!!